# How to change other page content using java script?

Tags: javascript

How do I change a content in another html page or pass the information by log in form using javascript? 
What I mean is, if I log in using as 'Zoe123' , the html page will show :

Welcome Zoe123
Your account has $100

Maybe can use the money amount to be hard-coded. It would help me with my school project. Help  me out!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a session issue, reading about PHP or other server-side scripting language would be better suited for your problem. Javascript wouldn't be that helpful.

You check articles about sessions in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or, with Java Server Faces, [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2421414?tstart=0)